# Optimize rails method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization, methods

I have to optimize this method because takes in processing 1000 objects 2-3 seconds

```
def children_progress
  descendants_array = descendants
  descendants = self.class.where(id: descendants_array.map(&:id))
  max_level = descendants.maximum(:level)

  descendants_leaves = descendants.where(level: max_level)
  if descendants_leaves.any?
    descendants_leaves_id = descendants_leaves.pluck(:id)
    node_ids = Plans::CategoriesNode.where(category_id: descendants_leaves_id).pluck(:node_id)
    nodes = Plans::Node.where(id: node_ids)
    nodes.average(:progress).to_f
  else
    0
  end
```

end

I know these small improvements:

- Change **any?** with **exists?** but it still takes two seconds.

Is it possible to optimize where? anything else? To make it take less than a second. Thanks!!!

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to do the whole calculation in one SQL query?
 What is `descendants` - a method or an association? How does your database schema look like? How are `Plans::Node`, `Plans::CategoriesNode`, `categories` and `descendants` connected?

Comment: Without knowing what `descendants` is, it seems to me the first two sentences don't do anything useful.

Comment: I would look into counter caches as a way to avoid count queries. You should also look carefully at the SQL generated and figure out how to avoid n+1 queries. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: You should also rewrite the entire question - you need to tell us what the method actually does and what the models and associations are to get anything more than vague advice or have the question closed.

Comment: can you add the model(s)? It's unclear what associations might exist between the various objects.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the equivalent of `where(category_id: descendants_leaves.pluck(:id))`, try `where(category_id: descendants_leaves.select(:id))`. ActiveRecord will insert the `.select()` into SQL as `category_id IN (SELECT id FROM ...)`. That way you have only one outer SELECT statement, instead of two, and the overhead of `map`ping all the first ones `id`s into Ruby variables.